# IOError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '40c0f5.xyz'

Tags: python, django, apache

I have built a Django application and deployed this application on apache2 server using wsgi.

```
pep_web/
|-- media
|-- out_put_files
|-- outputStr
|-- pep_learn
|-- PepStructure
|-- Peptide_Descriptor
|-- prediction
|-- protocol
|-- stepbystep
`-- Structure_Descriptor
```

"Peptide_Descriptor" APP of  Django Project  need to  write some temporary
 file.

But its showing an error:

```
IOError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '67fa042e47b74bd69fed5bfdf140c0f5.xyz'
```

and programe get aborted due to this error.

I have tried with  "chmod" method for directory permission but nothing has worked

```
sudo chmod -R 0755 /home/bic/pep_web
and 
sudo chmod -R 777 /home/bic/pep_web
```

complete error log is given bellow:

```
raceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/bic/pep_web/Structure_Descriptor/Structure_bassed_Descriptor_generation.py", line 161, in <module>
    Str_DS_class().main_process(args.pep, args.DesOut)
  File "/home/bic/pep_web/Structure_Descriptor/Structure_bassed_Descriptor_generation.py", line 114, in main_process
    Str_DS_class().structure_gen(my_pep)
  File "/home/bic/pep_web/Structure_Descriptor/Structure_bassed_Descriptor_generation.py", line 73, in structure_gen
    pep = Peptide(seq, nterm = "charged", cterm = "neutral")
  File "/home/bic/pep_web/Structure_Descriptor/fragbuilder/peptide.py", line 43, in __init__
    self._molecule = self._assemble_peptide(self._residues)
  File "/home/bic/pep_web/Structure_Descriptor/fragbuilder/peptide.py", line 221, in _assemble_peptide
    file_out = open(temp_xyz, "w")
IOError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '67fa042e47b74bd69fed5bfdf140c0f5.xyz'
```

Comment: are you sure that this file inside `/home/bic/pep_web`? Have you tried to **ch**ange **mod**e explicitly for this file?

Comment: this is not the actual error please check the APP behavior if you are using model or form

Comment: @Indrajit Swain yes I am using form but not model and this APP process form data successfully